# Comparing literal empty strings in C

Tags: c, string-comparison

In C, what is the following *specified* to do?

```
if ("" == "")
{
    printf("Empty strings are equal\n");
}
```

I have a compiler on hand that tells me that `""` is indeed equal to `""`. But is this equality guaranteed?

**Edit**: I understand perfectly well how pointer comparison and string comparison work in C. What I'm asking is what behavior, if any, is specified in the C standard for compile-time constant empty strings. My belief is that the strings are not guaranteed to be equal, but in practice usually will be equal since all const empty strings will be interned to the same address. But I want to know if anyone can provide a definitive reference

Comment: It's not guaranteed to have equality.  This has been [discussed before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843640/why-is-a-a-in-c) on SO.

Comment: Where you expecting something different?

Comment: My belief is that the strings are not *guaranteed* to be equal, but in practice usually will be equal since all const empty strings will be interned to the same address. But I want to know if anyone can provide a definitive reference.

Comment: The C Standard says (6.4.5/6): "It is unspecified whether [string literals] are distinct".

Comment: @pmg, that's what I was looking for. Make it an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Since both strings are compile-time constants, the entire expression seems a bit useless. Is there a real-world case when this really would matter?

Comment: @JSBangs: Consider to add your first comment to your question.

Comment: For what it's worth, the correct way to compare a string against the empty string is simply `if (!*string)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) says (6.4.5/6)

> It is unspecified whether [string literals] are distinct

Answer (score 5):

Guaranteed?  I doubt it.  You're not comparing the content of the strings but rather their addresses, which means that you're relying on the compiler to not emit two literal strings that happen to have the same content in the same location.  It's likely to work, but not something you should rely on (nor is it clear what it's useful for).

Edit: See also [Why is "a" != "a" in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843640/why-is-a-a-in-c) - it has an answer to basically the same question with nearly a hundred upvotes (and was written by a user whose compiler did it differently).

Comment: John Zwinck is right, you're betting on the compiler's behavior. You should be using strcmp instead - unless, of course, you're REALLY interested in comparing addresses.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any guarantee that these will have the same address -- I doubt the standard would require such behavior.  Why would you need to depend on this being predictable?