# argc argv problems

Tags: c, argv

Can someone please tell me why this code will not work? It does compile. When I type decrypt as the argv[1] argument in the command line, it still gives me the else output. i.e. argv[1] is not satisfied even though it should be. This is a work in progress so ignore the other code

```
 if ((argv[1] == "decrypt"))
      { 
      printf("Decrypting...\n");
        c = getc(fp1);
        if (c != EOF)
          { 
          fread(inputbuffer, sizeof(char), 50 , fp1);   
            printf("%s", inputbuffer);
            /*while(inputbuffer[i]!=EOF)
            {
            fputc((inputbuffer[i] / 2) - 5, fp2);
            }*/
          } 
      }

      else {printf("argv not working");}
```

Comment: use strcmp, or C++ with std::string

Comment: This has nothing to do with argc/argv, and everything to do with how strings are handled in C.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use `strcmp()` to compare strings:

```
if ((strcmp(argv[1], "decrypt") == 0)
```

[More detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843640/why-is-a-a-in-c/4843651#4843651):

> What you are comparing are the two memory addresses for the different strings, which are stored in different locations. Doing so essentially looks like this:
>
> ```
> if(0x00403064 == 0x002D316A) // Two memory locations
> {
>     printf("Yes, equal");
> }
> ```

Comment: I've changed it to strcmp and now the program crashes! It's not printing "Decrypting..." so its still the argv causing the problem   EDIT: fixed it my bad your solution was perfect thank you

Comment: @adohertyd:  Your code has other bugs in it, such as the possible non-null terminated string you're trying to print.  Also make sure `argc` is at least 2.