# compare two equal array in c but output shows unequal

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, c99

After a long break,I am back to C but getting confused even on some simple issues.
So one is here.

Here is the simple code :

```
 #include<stdio.h>

 int main() {

    char str1[]="hello";
    char str2[]="hello";

    if(str1==str2)
            printf("equal");  
    else
            printf("unequal");
}
```

**Output:**
unequal

but when I tried this one ,it worked

```
  char *str1="hello";
  char *str2="hello";
```

**Output**
equal

Please if anyone can provide a detailed explanation for it.
Can someone tell me what exactly does C99 standard say about the situation ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "a" != "a" in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843640/why-is-a-a-in-c)

Comment: @TimCooper thanx that was the post I was actually looking for but I could not find it out..thats really very helpful

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you do `==` with pointers (which is what `str1` and `str2` are in both cases<sup>1</sup>) all you are doing is comparing the two addresses to see if they are the same. When you do

```
char str1[]="hello";
char str2[]="hello";
```

You are creating two arrays on the stack that hold `"hello"`. They are certainly at different memory locations, so `str1 == str2` is `false`. This is like

```
char str1[6];
str1[0] = 'h';
str1[1] = 'e';
str1[2] = 'l';
str1[3] = 'l';
str1[4] = 'o';
str1[5] = '\0'; 

// and the same thing for str2
```

When you do

```
char *str1="hello";
char *str2="hello";
```

You are creating two pointers to the global data `"hello"`. The compiler, seeing that these string literals are the same and cannot be modified, will make the pointers point to the same address in memory, and `str1 == str2` is `true`.

To compare the *content* of two `char*`s, use `strcmp`:

```
// strcmp returns 0 if the two strings are equal
if (strcmp(str1, str2) == 0)
    printf("Equal");
else
    printf("Not equal");
```

This is roughly the equivalent of

```
char *a, *b;

// go through both strings, stopping when we reach a NULL in either string or
// if the corresponding characters in the strings don't match up
for (a = str1, b = str2; *a != '\0' && *b != '\0'; ++a, ++b)
    if (*a != *b)
        break;

// print Equal if both *a and *b are the NULL terminator in
// both strings (i.e. we advanced a and b to the end of both
// strings with the loop)
if (*a == '\0' && *b == '\0')
     printf("Equal");
else
     printf("Not equal");
```

---

<sup>1</sup> In the `char*` version, this is true. In the `char[]` version, `str1` and `str2` are really *arrays*, not pointers, however when used in `str1 == str2`, they decay to pointers to the first elements of the arrays, so they are the equivalent of pointers in that scenario.

Comment: thanx man ... It was a nice and detailed description.It really helped and I hope will help other begineers too ...thanx a lot

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing the pointers to the strings and not the strings themselves, but since they are two different strings, they are not "==" equal.

If you're comparing strings in C, you'll need to use strcmp(str1, str2) a'la

```
if(strcmp(str1, str2) == 0) {
```

A word of caution; if you had declared the strings as char* instead of char[], some compilers would actually show your comparison as equal, as the compiler realizes the two strings are equal and collapse them into one. That means, they'd both point to the same string, and the pointer comparison would be true.

Been bitten by that once, never again, darn VAX compiler... :)

Answer (score 0):

Strings (`char` pointers) in `C` must be compared with `strcmp()` or one of its sister functions.

Neither should *rightly* work (i.e. you should always use `strcmp()` when comparing strings), but the reason the latter one probably worked was is that in the second example, you have a single string in memory (probably), which is "hello", and both `str1` and `str2` end up pointing to it, as an optimization.

The first one, however, actually requires two separate character arrays to be created, so they aren't the same pointer.

Comment: Because he is comparing the pointers in his case and not the strings.

Comment: Thanx for the answer but I know that, I am interested in what exactly is going on here ??

Answer (score 0):

You aren't comparing the arrays, you are comparing the pointers to the data.  In the first case, when you declare char[] you get two different arrays at two addresses, so they are no equal.  In the second case, you get a constant array, so both pointers can get set the same address since the array is const can not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that when you use

*str1 = "hello";
*str2 = "hello";

The compiler may be optimizing this to use a single memory space and therefor str1 and str2 both would point to the same memory space.  However, when utilizing the array notation, the compiler is most likely creating two arrays in memory and therefor the pointers are pointing to different memory locations.

when using ==, it checks for equality of the pointers, not of the strings.

Answer (score 0):

In your first case you are comparing the pointers to the strings which, of course, are at two different positions and won't be equal. In the second case, you are comparing the two characters pointed to at the beginning of the string which are both 'h' and, of course, equal.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, **the second one can also be `unequal`**.  Being `equal` on most platforms are possible of compiler optimization, because these two `hello` strings do not necessarily have to be stored in the same static memory space.