# C: How to compare two strings?

Tags: c, string, compare

**Edit:** This is a duplicate and I've flagged it as such. See [question] [Why is "a" != "a" in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843640/why-is-a-a-in-c)

So I'm trying to print out a specific message depending on a field within a struct. The field contains the string "1".

Whenever I run `printf("%s", record.fields[2]);`  the output is `1`; I've no format warnings.

However, when I check the field against the corresponding string (in this case, "1"), it fails the check:

```
if (record.fields[2] == "1") {
    printf("The field is 1!");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`strncmp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/strncmp.html) to compare strings:

```
if (strncmp(record.fields[2], "1", 1) == 0) ...
```

You need to compare to zero, because `strcmp` returns zero when two strings are identical.

However, it looks like you are not comparing strings: rather, you are looking for a specific character inside the string. In this case, you need to use a character constant instead of a string literal (with single quotes):

```
if (record.fields[2] == '1') ...
```

Comment: In case record.fields is a `char*`, OP should be using the character '1' as the comparison target

Comment: @hd1 You're right, strncmp is better. Edited. Thanks!

Comment: @PolyShell Please take a look at the edit.

Comment: Again, @PolyShell, what does the declaration of record.fields look like?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks for the edit, that was the issue and I'm good to go and on my way. I can always count on Stack Overflow to help me through a tough spot!

Comment: As long as one of the arguments is guaranteed to have a `NULL` terminator (as is the case here with `"1"`), I see no reason to use `strncmp` rather than `strcmp`.

Comment: @Joshua Green Should the field `.field` be <= size than the `strlen("123")`, and `.field` is not `'\0'` terminated, then `strncmp(record.fields[2], "123", sizeof record.fields[2])` has an advantage over `strcmp(record.fields[2], "123")` as it prevents comparing past the size of `record.fields[2]`.  Of course, with `"1"`, the point is moot.