# If logical condition with string in C

Tags: c, string, equality

```
puts("Type your name");
gets(name);
if(name=="exit"){
    exit(0);
}
```

My logical conditional in if is wrong, how I can repair it?

Comment: How is it wrong? What do you expect it to do and what does it do instead? Do you get error messages?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is "a" != "a" in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843640/why-is-a-a-in-c)

Comment: Which book are you reading?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `name` is a string why don't you use `strcmp` function?

```
if (strcmp(name, "exit") == 0)
{
  exit(0);
}
```

Comment: yeah, I forgot to use strcmp, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can't compare strings that way, use [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/), or preferably, [strncmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncmp/)

Comment: Why do you recommend `strncmp`?  That'd give a false positive for any string starting "exit".

Comment: Hmm, that's right, but it is slightly safer.

Comment: @Kninnug No. None of the strings are being written, so `strncmp()` is not any safer. No risk for buffer overflow for properly NUL-terminated strings at all.