# Iterating over a std map and comparing text

Tags: c++, dictionary

I am currently something something like this

```
std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it ;
for(it=mmap.begin();it!=mmap.end();it++)
{
    if(it->second.c_str() != "qa" && it->second.c_str() != "qb")
    {
        //Entered
    }
}
```

Now the problem with this code is that it goes into the entered section even when the iterator is

```
it("Testing this","qb")
```

Thee above means that `it->second = "qb"`

Now my question is why is the code going ino the if statement if `it->second = "qb"` My thought is that it should not have because the conditional statment part is `it->second.c_str() != "qb"`

Comment: try `if(it->second != "qa" && it->second != "qb")`.

Comment: [Possible Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843640/why-is-a-a-in-c/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is because `it->second.c_str() != "qa"` is not the correct way to compare C strings (it compares pointers and not the string contents). You however do not need to convert to a C string first before comparing as you can compare the strings directly with: `it->second != "qa"`. If you for some reason need to use the c string with `c_str()` then you will need to use `strcmp`.

Answer (score 3):

c_str() is a character array (pointer), so you are comparing two pointers which are different.

Use string objects instead:

```
std::string QA("qa");
std::string QB("qb");
std::map<std::string,std::string>::iterator it ;
for(it=mmap.begin();it!=mmap.end();it++)
{
    if(it->second != QA && it->second  != QB)
    {
        //Entered
    }
}
```

or actually do C style string compare:

```
    if ( strcmp(it->second.c_str(), "qa") != 0 && strcmp(it->second.c_str(), "qb") != 0 )
```

Comment: You can compare directly on the right hand side with a null-terminated `C`-string, no need for `QA` and `QB`.

Comment: If you are going to have a `QA` and a `QB`, they should be declared as constant strings.