# How to detect carriage return in C?

Tags: c, return, checksum

For my homework we are supposed to write a checksum that continues to display checksums until a carriage return is detected (Enter key is pressed). My checksum works fine and continues to prompt me for a string to convert it to a checksum, but my program is supposed to end after I press the enter key. In my code, I set up a while loop that continues to calculate the checksums. In particular I put:

```
while(gets(s) != "\r\n")
```

Where s in a string that the user has to input. I've also tried this with scanf, and my loop looked like:

```
while(scanf("%s",s) != '\n')
```

That did not work as well. Could anyone please give me some insight onto how to get this to work? Thanks

Comment: You cannot compare C strings with the assignment operator '='.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843640/why-is-a-a-in-c/4843651#4843651

Comment: The answers are right that you need something like strcmp, but gets and scanf %s don't return the newline so the comparison will still fail. Check for an empty string instead

Comment: Never, ever use `gets`. Replace it with `fgets`. `gets` is a horribly dangerous function and has been deprecated. Also, `fgets` will return the newline unlike `gets` which strips it.

Answer (score 0):

The [`gets(s)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/gets/?kw=gets) returns s.  Your condition compares this pointer to the adress of a constant string litteral.  It will never be equal. You have to use `strcmp()` to compare two strings.

You should also take care of special circumstances, such as end of file by checking for [`!feof(stdin)`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/feof/) and of other reading errors in which case `gets()` returns NULL.

Please note that `gets()` will read a full line until '\n' is encountered.  The '\n' is not part of the string that is returned. So `strcmp(s,"\r\n")!=0` will always be true.

Try:

```
while (!feof(stdin) && gets(s) && strcmp(s,""))
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases the `stdin` stream inserts '\n' (newline or line-feed) when enter is pressed rather than carriage-return or LF+CR.

```
char ch ;
while( (ch = getchar()) != '\n` )
{
     // update checksum using ch here
}
```

However also be aware that normally functions operating on `stdin` do not return until a newline is inserted into the stream, so displaying an updating checksum while entering characters is not possible.  In the loop above, an entire line will be buffered before `getchar()` first returns, and then all buffered characters will be updated at once.

Answer (score -1):

To compare a string in C, which is actually a pointer to an array of characters, you need to individually compare the values of each character of the string.

Comment: Or use `strcmp()`/`strncmp()`